# Using data://text/plain when including files in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to `require_once()` a string of PHP code. It works well except when using namespaced classes, this always results in a fatal error. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
require_once('data://text/plain, <?php namespace Foo\Bar; use \Somestuff; class Baz {...}
```

It seems significant that the error message also starts output in the middle of the included code:

```
Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in data://text/plain, $prop; } throw new InvalidArgumentException('
```

The code "$prop; } throw new InvalidArgumentException('" is a few lines down in the class I'm trying to include.

I've tried this on both 5.4 and 5.6 with the same result.

What is the correct way to approach this? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: You're inside PHP already, so why use `<?php`?

Comment: @fred Otherwise it does not evaluate as code

Comment: I didn't even know that was possible. Could you just use `eval` instead?

Comment: I recommend just using an auto-loader. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: *Hm....* ok fair enough.

Comment: @Fred Any include or eval starts in non-code context. Otherwise, library files would never need opening tags.

Comment: @IMSoP wow eval() seems to work, what is the difference?

Comment: @IMSoP *Interesting.*

Comment: @IMSOP: Possible yes, probable no :-)

Comment: Note that although you're using a very unusual method of achieving the same thing, the quote in the comments of [the `eval()` manual page](http://php.net/eval) applies equally here: "If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question."

Comment: @Fred-ii- Actually, I'm slightly wrong, `eval()` starts in code context; everything else starts in output context, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space after the comma and before the opening `<?php`.  Everything after the comma is "output".  The space may not break all code, but obviously `namespace` and any session use, etc. will break.  Remove the space:

```
require_once('data://text/plain,<?php namespace Foo\Bar; use \Somestuff; class Baz {}');
```